# How to start typescript with Node.js, Express and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, typescript

I am very new to typescript with node js , express and MongoDB, I need end to end flow please anyone can you suggest me or any links/Anyone give me step by step.

1. How to compile/run this application ?
2. How to deploy this type of application?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

there. I think that [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application) tutorial from Scotch.io shows almost all you need for setting up a NodeJS app with MongoDB and Express. It shows some Angular1 example but you can ignore the Angular part. Moreover, in your public directory you can place your `.ts` files and install TypeScript via the NPM package manager. Then you can check out [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) tutorial for Angular2 and see how to organize and compile your files using TypeScript.